# T-SQL to join system tables to values in user tables SYS.TABLES, SYS.TYPES, SYS.COLUMNS

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have this query that selects the tables like CODE_. I want to join these results to each CODE table like CODE_COUNTRY, CODE_COUNTY to list the value of the SHORT_DESC, it will be values like: United States, Mexico for Country; Brown, Green for County; Male, Female For Gender*. The value in the SHORT_DESC matches the value in the Transformations Table PC_Column*. So I need to join to the Transformations table to find the columns that match. And do left join, right joins to show columns that don't match either database. How do I find the system column to join to the Transformations table?

```
SELECT tb.[schema_id] AS 'Schema'
   ,tb.[OBJECT_ID] AS 'TableObj'
   ,tb.[NAME] AS 'TableName' 
   ,C.NAME as 'Column'
   ,T.name AS 'Type'
   ,C.max_length
   ,C.is_nullable
FROM 
    SYS.COLUMNS C 
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.TABLES tb ON tb.[object_id] = C.[object_id]
INNER JOIN 
    SYS.TYPES T ON C.system_type_id = T.user_type_id
--INNER JOIN 
--    Bridge_test.dbo.Transformations TF ON TF.PC_Column = C.NAME
WHERE
    tb.[is_ms_shipped] = 0 
    AND tb.[NAME] LIKE '%code_%'
    AND C.name = 'SHORT_DESC'
    --C.NAME LIKE '%country%'
ORDER BY 
    tb.[Name]
```

*Note: these are the columns to add to this query

query result

```
Schema  TableObj    TableName   Column  Type    max_length  is_nullable *SHORT_DESC Value (from CODE_ table),  *PC_Column (from Transformations table)
1   1826105546  CODE_COUNTRY    SHORT_DESC  nvarchar    20  0 United States, USA
1   2018106230  CODE_COUNTY SHORT_DESC  nvarchar    20  0 Mexico, Mexico
```

For example, the value in the SHORT_DESC should match the PC_Column

```
CODE_VALUE_KEY  CODE_VALUE  SHORT_DESC  MEDIUM_DESC LONG_DESC   STATUS
1001    1001    Autauga Autauga Autauga A
1003    1003    Baldwin Baldwin Baldwin A
1005    1005    Barbour Barbour Barbour A
1007    1007    Bibb    Bibb    Bibb    A
1009    1009    Blount  Blount  Blount  A

Transformations Table
    GM_Column   Value   Note1   F4  PC_Table_Column PC_Table    PC_Column   Value1  Note2   F10
    Ugender M   NULL    =   demographics_gender demographics    gender  Male    NULL    NULL
    Ugender F   NULL    =   demographics_gender demographics    gender  Female  NULL    NULL
    Ugender U   NULL    =   demographics_gender demographics    gender  Unknown NULL    NULL
    Umarstat    D   NULL    =   demographics_marital_status demographics    marital_status  Divorced    NULL    NULL
    Umarstat    M   NULL    =   demographics_marital_status demographics    marital_status  Married NULL    NULL
    Umarstat    O   NULL    =   demographics_marital_status demographics    marital_status  Other   NULL    NULL
    Umarstat    S   NULL    =   demographics_marital_status demographics    marital_status  Single  NULL    NULL
```

Sytem Tables  --queried system tables to find a common column with user data and don't see a common column to join to the user data tables

```
SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%code%'                                                                                                       

/*                                                                                                      
name    object_id   principal_id    schema_id   parent_object_id    type    type_desc   create_date modify_date is_ms_shipped   is_published    is_schema_published lob_data_space_id   filestream_data_space_id    max_column_id_used  lock_on_bulk_load   uses_ansi_nulls is_replicated   has_replication_filter  is_merge_published  is_sync_tran_subscribed has_unchecked_assembly_data text_in_row_limit   large_value_types_out_of_row    is_tracked_by_cdc   lock_escalation lock_escalation_desc
CODE_SOURCETYPE 5195785 NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:44.0 16:28.9 0   0   0   0   NULL    18  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
CODE_CONTROLTYPE    8671795 NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:37.8 16:28.9 0   0   0   0   NULL    17  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
CODE_SPONSORSTATUS  21195842    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:44.1 16:29.0 0   0   0   0   NULL    19  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
CODE_COUNTRY    24671852    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:37.8 16:29.0 0   0   0   0   NULL    24  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
CODE_SPONSORTYPE    37195899    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:44.1 16:29.2 0   0   0   0   NULL    17  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
CODE_COUNTY 40671909    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:37.9 16:29.2 0   0   0   0   NULL    18  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
CODE_STATE  53195956    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:44.2 16:29.3 0   0   0   0   NULL    19  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
CODE_CREDCARDTYPE   56671966    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  45:38.0 16:29.3 0   0   0   0   NULL    17  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
*/                                                                                                      

SELECT      * FROM sys.objects WHERE type = 'U' --user tables                                                                                                       
/*                                                                                                      
has table name                                                                                                      
name    object_id   principal_id    schema_id   parent_object_id    type    type_desc   create_date modify_date is_ms_shipped   is_published    is_schema_published                                                         
ADDRESSSCHEDULE 7671075 NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:10.6 03:14.2 0   0   0                                                           
ADVANCENAME 23671132    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:10.7 03:10.7 0   0   0                                                           
COMBINEMAILING  55671246    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:11.1 03:11.1 0   0   0                                                           
DEMOGRAPHICS    87671360    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:11.4 03:11.4 0   0   0                                                           
*/                                                                                                      
SELECT      * FROM sys.columns                                                                                                      
/*                                                                                                      
has column name                                                                                                     
object_id   name    column_id   system_type_id  user_type_id    max_length  precision   scale   collation_name  is_nullable is_ansi_padded  is_rowguidcol   is_identity is_computed is_filestream   is_replicated   is_non_sql_subscribed   is_merge_published  is_dts_replicated   is_xml_document xml_collection_id   default_object_id   rule_object_id  is_sparse   is_column_set       
119671474   HONORS  10  231 231 12  0   0   SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS    1   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       
119671474   TRANSCRIPT_DATE 11  61  61  8   23  3   NULL    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       
119671474   CLASS_RANK  12  56  56  4   10  0   NULL    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       
119671474   CLASS_SIZE  13  56  56  4   10  0   NULL    1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0       
*/                                                                                                      
SELECT      * FROM sys.tables                                                                                                       
/*                                                                                                      
has table name                                                                                                      
name    object_id   principal_id    schema_id   parent_object_id    type    type_desc   create_date modify_date is_ms_shipped   is_published    is_schema_published lob_data_space_id   filestream_data_space_id    max_column_id_used  lock_on_bulk_load   uses_ansi_nulls is_replicated   has_replication_filter  is_merge_published  is_sync_tran_subscribed has_unchecked_assembly_data text_in_row_limit   large_value_types_out_of_row    is_tracked_by_cdc   lock_escalation lock_escalation_desc
ADDRESSSCHEDULE 7671075 NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:10.6 03:14.2 0   0   0   0   NULL    39  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
ADVANCENAME 23671132    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:10.7 03:10.7 0   0   0   0   NULL    18  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
COMBINEMAILING  55671246    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:11.1 03:11.1 0   0   0   0   NULL    16  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
DEMOGRAPHICS    87671360    NULL    1   0   U   USER_TABLE  03:11.4 03:11.4 0   0   0   0   NULL    31  0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   TABLE
*/                                                                                                      
SELECT      * FROM sys.tables WHERE name LIKE '%code%'                                                                                                      
SELECT      * FROM systypes                                                                                                     
/*                                                                                                      
has column type                                                                                                     
name    xtype   status  xusertype   length  xprec   xscale  tdefault    domain  uid reserved    collationid usertype    variable    allownulls  type    printfmt    prec    scale   collation                           
text    35  0   35  16  0   0   0   0   4   0   872468488   19  0   1   35  NULL    NULL    NULL    SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS                            
uniqueidentifier    36  0   36  16  0   0   0   0   4   0   NULL    0   0   1   37  NULL    16  NULL    NULL                            
date    40  0   40  3   10  0   0   0   4   0   NULL    0   0   1   0   NULL    10  0   NULL                            
time    41  0   41  5   16  7   0   0   4   0   NULL    0   0   1   0   NULL    16  7   NULL                            
datetime2   42  0   42  8   27  7   0   0   4   0   NULL    0   0   1   0   NULL    27  7   NULL                            
datetimeoffset  43  0   43  10  34  7   0   0   4   0   NULL    0   0   1   0   NULL    34  7   NULL                            
...                                                                                                     
34 rows                                                                                                     
*/
```

I'm using SQL Server 2008 R2

I posted on a sheet for formatting 
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1k3rubaSm0M4jXf5VKgk3DuS8QkuPwgzPZYJnsMJdQcI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you need information schema involved? Despite the range of information given I don't grasp the actual problem. Or your data model needs quita an overhaul if you are tring to dynamically match fata to column names you are stuck with dynammic sql forever

Comment: We can't over haul our data model it's an old third party database.

Comment: I'm doing application integration, posting data from ERP to CRM, and data warehouse for reports. We always have to compare data types, and transaction coding. That's the only way I know to post data from one system to another and get it to be compatible with the application. If the coding doesnt match the data will be in the database but the application won't display it because the data doesn't match.